# Scripted Pipeline set and access environment variables

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using scripted Jenkins Pipeline to execute my build. One of my stages calls ant with parameters to build the executable. I read that I can use **withEnv** step to pass variables:

```
node(this.JENKINS_NODE_LABEL) {
    withEnv ([
        'JAVA1_8 = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk',
        'ANT_HOME = ant-1.7.1',
        'ANT_OPTS = -Xmx512m',
        'PATH = $ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH',
        'COMPONENT_NAME = SampleName'
        ]) {
            buildComponent()
        }
}
```

The buildComponent stage is defined inside an additional file and it contains just one step to execute a build:

```
def call() {
    stage('Build Component') {
        sh 'ant -Dcomponent=$COMPONENT_NAME'
    }
}
```

However, when I execute it I am receiving an exception that ant is not recognized and the value passed as the component is empty. I tried to use also env.COMPONENT_NAME but without luck. How should I set and access environment variables inside Scripted Pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will completely solve your issue, but I believe it's the first problem: you need to remove the spaces either side of the `=` in the environment variable strings. It's a list of Strings, rather than a Map of keys to values, so it will be passed as-is to a shell, similar to how you'd pass an environment variable to a command if running it in a shell manually, for example:

```
MYVAR=value /usr/bin/mycommand
```

rather than

```
MYVAR = value /usr/bin/mycommand
```

A basic example in a pipeline script -- the following will print `world`:

```
withEnv(['HELLO=world']) {
    print env.HELLO
}
```

but this will print `null`, because of the spaces either side of the `=`:

```
withEnv(['HELLO = world']) {
    print env.HELLO
}
```

Comment: Thank you - it fixed the problem!

Comment: def someList=['hostname=server','username=user1','password=password@123']
       withEnv('$someList'){
              // do some code
             echo env.hostname
      }

while i used above code in my pipeline to display environment variable 
echo env.hostname is not displaying.. can you pls help me in this?